# Mysql remote connection

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql db . One is 10.0.3.129, another is 10.0.3.139. I want to connect 10.0.3.129 from 10.0.3.139. Could someone tell me what should I do with 10.0.3.139 and 10.0.3.129 ? ?  Thank you .

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. I want to connect 10.0.3.129 from 10.0.3.139. And I can execute a sql program from 10.0.3.139, the 10.0.3.129's mysql db can have effect.

Comment: Are you asking about MySQL instance replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure that MySQL port is open for connection from `10.0.3.139` to `10.0.3.129`, verify using

  `telnet 10.0.3.129:<MySQL port>` where you have configured your server.
  Create a MySQL user in `10.0.3.139` like:
- Create MySQL user in server by executing this query

  CREATE USER 'test'@'10.0.3.139' IDENTIFIED BY 'test123';

and given proper permission to this user by using `GRANT` syntax.

- Now try to connect using MySQL command line or any GUI tool from `10.0.3.139`, it should work.